# How could I make the SWRevealViewController available on all my scene?

Tags: swift, xcode7, swrevealviewcontroller

I am creating an App on Xcode7 using swift and I really need some help. I would like to make the SWRevealViewController sidebar appear on all of my scene but the problem is it only appears on the first view controller I set the push segue to show. And also upon clicking a link on the sidebar the navigation bar disappears on the next scene? Please somebody help...

[sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBDHF.jpg)

[image]

Here is the script I used on my UITableViewController for the sidebar links

```
var catArrayId = [String]()
var catArrayName = [String]()
var catArrayImg2 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad(){

    // get available categories according to customer country
    get_categories()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return catArrayId.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("navCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.catArrayName[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCategory", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCategory" {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! CategoryProductsViewController

        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let categoryImage = UIImage(named: catArrayImg2[indexPath.row])

        VC.catId = self.catArrayId[indexPath.row]
        VC.image = categoryImage!

    }
}

func get_categories(){
    let country_id = 168
    //let startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    let pageUrl = "https://domain.com/ios/home-categories-image.php?country_id=\(country_id)&uudi=" + NSUUID().UUIDString
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: pageUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (let data, let response, let error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        do{
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            let catArray = json as? [[String: AnyObject]]
            for catArr in catArray!{

                let catName = catArr["name"] as? String
                let catID = catArr["id"] as? String
                let img2 = catArr["image2"] as? String

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.catArrayId.append(catID!)
                    self.catArrayName.append(catName!)
                    self.catArrayImg2.append(img2!)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("Error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: how do you add the SWRevealViewController?  via a storyboard/xib file or programmatically in code?  If you're doing it via code, could you edit your question to show how you add it, and where (i.e. is it being added in the first view controller?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, then you can do the same as in example provided by an author of controller ("RevealControllerStoryboardExample2"). When you select something from rear VC, segue for that action needs to have class "SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController". Here is a screenshot of this example:[image]